# Parse.com is crashing on iOS7 only

Tags: parse-platform

We have a crash on real iPhone4, that happens only in iPhone4 (not iPhone6 nor simulator).

The crash is happens here :

```
 PFQuery *getRelevantRows=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Que"];
[getRelevantRows orderByDescending:@"updatedAt"];
getRelevantRows.limit=150;
//getRelevantRows.skip=skip;

 //query log has a value(number) here.

[getRelevantRows findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
//no log here.
```

on the row that find objects on the server.

The crash report is:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'
```

and its on the row:

```
PfmultiProcessFileLockController
```

We use the latest SDKs of Parse. We can't release now, what could it be?

Comment: If that is something you can consistently reproduce, you should file a bug report at parse.com/help with all the logs you get and the minimal code required to reproduce it, your best option here IMHO

Comment: @BjörnKaiser problem is that you cant even downgrade. there is no place to download previous version of parse.??

Comment: They distribute the SDK via Cocoapods as well, go find the Podspec of an older version which includes a direct download link as far as I remember. You should still report the bug though

Comment: take a look to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609806/parse-key-cannot-be-nil-error-on-pfobject-saveinbackground-cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609806/parse-key-cannot-be-nil-error-on-pfobject-saveinbackground-cocoa). Maybe you are using the query before Parse completed the setup.